# API docs for gl-rs (Rust OpenGL bindings)

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust, and I'm using [gl-rs](https://github.com/bjz/gl-rs). The [project's page](http://rust-ci.org/bjz/gl-rs) on rust-ci.org doesn't have a documentation link.

Are the API docs available anywhere? Or, are there certain rules by which I can infer the Rust API based on the C API? In particular, I'd like to know type info for the Rust API. So, for example, how could I look up what the argument types are for `gl::TexImage2d`?

Comment: It looks like the [TravisCI config](https://github.com/bjz/gl-rs/blob/master/.travis.yml) for that project is attempting to upload the docs to rust-ci.org. Perhaps filing a bug with the project would be the best course of action.

Answer (score 2):

It should be uploading the docs to rust-ci, but rust-ci's upload script almost never seems to work. You can, however, pull the project and generate the latest documentation using `cargo doc`.

Comment: I tried to build the docs, but this project seems to have a more-complex-than-usual build setup. It doesn't quite come out of the box, as far as I see.

Comment: Thus far for me, `cargo doc` crashes for `gl-rs`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is official, but this site does seem to have the documentation: http://bvssvni.github.io/docs/gl-rs/gl/

It is likely to be out of date at this point, however, as [this webpage was created in May 2014.](https://github.com/bvssvni/bvssvni.github.io/commit/ddb2a7d7b8adae05a6a3c8325c630836bc255b2a)